# SSIS Package strange data flow issue, spitting out empty excel with large dataset

Tags: excel, ssis

I am having issue with the SSIS package, by Running from BIDS I could export 400K records successfully, But when I tried to run from the Job the package ran successfully but the excel file is empty.

The user which I am running the package with having the full access to the C:\Users folders. and I see it saving the data into the temporary folder but not writing that data into the file and finish with empty file.

For example : 230000 records (works good) 
Create the excel file
Load the temporary data
Write data into the file
close the file

330000 records (not working) 
Create the excel file
Load the temporary data
Write data into the file xxxxxxx this line missing from the process monitor
close the file

Solution : give permission to the user executing the package to the folder C:\Users\Default doesn't work for me.

Please help!

Comment: If the record count is the only thing you have changed maybe you have reached some kind of Excel limit. What excel version do you use?

Comment: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data. Excel is ok with 230000 records. If I exceed it, it wont work . Though it works in BIDS

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bugging you guys, Found the problem. There was just 1.6GB of disk space on the server, thought the file is taking just 200MB of space but generate lots of temporary files causing the disk full error. Strange that SSIS package ran successfully without giving any warning or error. Thanks for looking into it.